# How to make the code works with multiple files python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import glob
Path3 = "e:/teste/xxx/Filtrados/"
    Path4 = "e:/teste/xxx/FiltradosFinal/"
    filelist = os.listdir(Path3)                             
    _03000_text = ''
    output = []
    for x in filelist:
        if x.endswith(".txt"):
            print(f"Processando Arquivo {x}")
            with open(Path3 + x, "r", encoding="utf-8") as data, open(Path4 + x, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f_out: 
                for line in data:
                    if not line.startswith("03"):
                        output.append(line)
                        continue

                    if line.startswith("03000"):
                        _03000_text = "|".join(line.split("|")[:-1])
                        output.append(line)
                        continue

                    line = _03000_text + "|" + line
                    output.append(line)

                output = "\n".join(output)
                print(output, file=f_out)
```

The first file of the folder process fine, but at the second one I get this error:

```
    output.append(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Anyone can help me fix the code so it works with multiples files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `output = "\n".join(output)`, you make `output` a string, so you cannot call `.appand` on it on the next iteration.

Replace the last to lines with:

```
string_output = "\n".join(output)
print(string_output, file=f_out)
```

If you don't want to keep the output to the next iteration, just move the line `output = []` one line down (make it the first line in the for loop).